# One word for a person who doesn't act before thinking

Tags: single-word-requests

What is one word for a person who thinks before they act? Like they think of the effects of doing something before they actually do it.

**Example sentence:**
Ally is________, she always thinks before acting.

Comment: @StoneyB I initially read it that way myself but they're looking for the opposite   .. cautious ?

Comment: The title is the complete opposite of what you're looking for.

Comment: Obviously, it's *evislupmi*.

Comment: But if you want a person who doesn't act before thinking I'd go with *indolent*.

Comment: sensible, rational

Answer (score 3):

Prudent is what I'd go with, but there's also:

Cautious: adjective
1. showing, using, or characterized by alertness and prudence

Answer (score 2):

> ***deliberate*** [dicitonary.com definition of deliberate](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/deliberate)
>
> [adjective dih-lib-er-it; verb dih-lib-uh-reyt] adjective
>
> 1.
>   carefully weighed or considered; studied; intentional:
>   *a deliberate lie.*
>
> 2.
>   characterized by deliberation or cautious consideration; careful or slow in deciding:

Answer (score 1):

**prudent**

1. wise or judicious in practical affairs; sagacious; discreet or circumspect; sober.
   2.
   careful in providing for the future; provident:
   a prudent decision.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/prudent?s=t

Answer (score 1):

The word "circumspect" fits well with your given example.

> ***circumspect*** *(adj.)*
>
> 1. heedful of potential consequences

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few examples that may assist you:

**Incisive** |in'sīsiv| adj. – (of a person or mental process) intelligently analytical and clear-thinking

**Rational** |raSH(ə)n(ə)l| adj. – based on or in accordance with reason or logic
- (of a person) able to think clearly, sensibly, and logically

**Sensible** |'sensəb(ə)l| adj. – (of a statement or course of action) chosen in accordance with wisdom or prudence; likely to be of benefit
- (of a person) possessing or displaying prudence

**Judicious** |jo͞o'diSHəs| adj. – having, showing, or done with good judgement or sense

**Discerning** |d'sərniNG| adj. – having or showing good judgement

**Prudent** |'pro͞odnt| adj. – acting with or showing care and thought for the future

Answer (score -1):

*foresighted* (adj),  "Ally is ***foresighted***, she always thinks before acting".

> **[foresight](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/foresight)**
>
> *the ability to judge correctly what is going to happen in the future and plan your actions based on this knowledge:*

Comment: The question asks for a word that indicates that thinking is done, not that the thinking is correct.